# 4B having issues with USB serial and booting with USB ports populated

Tags: pi-3, usb, pi-4, serial

first time OP'er here I have two issues which I do not know if they are related.

Some quick background about my setup
I have 4B 4GB pi. I have 3 USB2.0 webcams, the webcams have their cables spliced to be powered from an external power supply. (This was necessary for the 3B, to run simultaneously.). I also have an arduino uno which is also connected via USB, where I read data from.

Now on to my first issue. The 4B does not want to boot with all four ports populated with the cams and the arduino, but it boots just fine with nothing connected. NOTE: I am using a 5V 3A power supply to power the pi. I have no idea why this is happening.

My second issue, is I cannot read serial data from the arduino to the pi via C++ or terminal. I made sure all my parameters were correct. I installed putty on to the pi and I see data coming out just fine. On my 3B, my C++ code and via terminal read from the arduino just fine.
I used the below in terminal but it did not work as well.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

One more thing to note, the serial communication did work only once.

Any ideas on what this could be?

EDIT:
I reinstalled buster with the same issue. I also tried an app call Screen and it worked. So both Screen and Putty worked but not in terminal or C++.

Comment: You should make two questions.

Comment: I would but it may be that solving one may solve the other